# Server Error in '/' Application. Active Directory

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

ASP.NET - C# and Active Directory

(prior bad PW error was 'SQL Server Express database file auto-creation error' but is now 'Server Error in '/' Application')

I get this error only when authenticating against a remote Active Directory using an incorrect PW after around 10 seconds or more or clocking.  There is no error or clocking when using the correct User ID and PW.

Any direction would be appreciated as I cannot find any solutions for this anywhere.

Someone else had the same error but with no real resolution: http://www.44342.com/dotnet-framework-f1218-t1192-p1.htm

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) +970
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +458
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +507
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +141
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +362
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
>      System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) +75
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server
>   database.]
>   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server,
>   String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String
>   connectionString) +125
>   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.SetupApplicationServices(String
>   server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String
>   connectionString, String database, String dbFileName, SqlFeatures
>   features, Boolean install) +89
>   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.Install(String database, String
>   dbFileName, String connectionString) +29
>   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String
>   fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString) +386

---

Also I have used PrincipalContext in the past and it kicked a similar error with a bad password.

This is the code I use currently:

```
public static string fValidUser2(string sUser, string sPW)
    {
        string sDomain_LDAP = "LDAP://domain.com";

        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(sDomain_LDAP, sUser, sPW);
            object nativeObject = entry.NativeObject;
            return "FOUND";
        }
        catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException cex)
        {
            //not authenticated; reason why is in cex
    return "NOT FOUND";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //not authenticated due to some other exception [this is optional]
    return "NOT FOUND";
        }
    }
```

called from:

```
protected void Unnamed6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            string sUserState = clActiveDirectory.fValidUser2(this.frameLogin.UserName, this.frameLogin.Password);

            if (sUserState == "FOUND")
            {
                Session["name"] = this.frameLogin.UserName; 

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(this.frameLogin.UserName, createPersistentCookie: false); 

                Response.Redirect("/Default.aspx")
            }
            else
            {

                string sErr = sUserState;
                this.lblStatus.Text = sErr;
                sErr = sErr.Replace("\t", string.Empty);
                sErr = sErr.Replace("\n", string.Empty);
                sErr = sErr.Replace("\r", string.Empty);
                string sRedirect = "~/Error.aspx?error=Login: " + sErr;
                Response.Redirect(sRedirect, false);

            }
```

}

It processes in a timely manor - gives me a "NOT FOUND" return, processes all the code but then clocks and finally presents the SQL Server Express database file auto-creation error Active Directory error from this location: `http://localhost:99999/Account/Login.aspx`

Comment: It explicitly said that application cannot connect to SQL Server with the given credential. At first, you can try to connect with SSMS using same credential.

Comment: That would be correct as the credential is wrong (invalid password)... the problem is that the user gets this error if they enter an incorrect PW.  I need to either disable or suppress this error and replace it with a meaningful message for the user that they entered the wrong ID or PW.